# Windows Live password not working (.edu domain)

Tags: sync, microsoft-account, password, accounts

My Windows Live account is actually a University of Massachusetts domain, it is also my outlook account and my developer account.

Since the beggining of Windows Phone, my settings account page shows "Attention Required" under my live account. I tap it and it says my live password is incorrect. It has been like that this whole time, across many devices and even through several password changes (my first attempt to reconcile the error was to make a new password).

However, I have no problem getting my messaging notifications from twitter/fb/linkedIn through my live account. (My emails, calendar, and contacts are through my outlook which also uses the same ID and doesnt give me an incorrect password error). I dont have any problem downloading, installing and buying apps, which happens through my live ID as well.

Has this happened to anyone else? Were you able to fix it, if so, how did you fix it?

Comment: So it always asks for your password, but gives you the data anyway?

Comment: yeah, there doesnt appear to be any loss of priviledge anywhere. I just feel like there's gotta be something the phone isnt getting because of this. There is one glitch I see, when sliding over to the "online" pivot in the messaging hub, I get an "Incorrect Password" MessageBox. I then can hit settings or cancel. If I hit cancel, my chat works fine...

Comment: Have you tried some contacts with WinPhoneSupport via Twitter?

Comment: I spoke with them and they're investigating the issue with my school's server not linking into the Live service properly. Write an answer below containing the WinPhoneSupport links so I can give you credit for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the [official support twitter account of Windows Phone](https://twitter.com/#!/WinPhoneSupport) can help. They can ask someone that has the answer.

Tweet to WinPhoneSupport 9:00am-5:00pm Pacific